# Delete a folder using starts with in ANT

Tags: ant, comparison, delete-file, fileset, dirset

I am comparing 2 folders A and B, and wanted to delete folders and jars present in B which are not present in folder A.

I have written the logic to get needed files to delete, but i do not wanted to delete the directory and jars starting with "**com.ibm**".

For that I have written delete task as below:

```
<delete>
    <dirset dir="D://mypath/plugins<Filename to delete> excludes="**/com.ibm.*/**" />
</delete>
```

I have tried the excludes with the scenarios like:

```
excludes="**/com.ibm.*/**"
excludes="**/com.ibm.*"
excludes="com.ibm.*"
excludes="com.ibm.*/**"
```

But nothing works for me (It is not deleting any folders/files). Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you should use `fileset` instead and specify `includeemptydirs="true"` of `delete`.

```
<project default="init" name="My Project">

    <target name="init">
        <delete verbose="true" includeemptydirs="true">
            <fileset dir="/home/guest/Desktop/plugins" defaultexcludes="no">
                <exclude name="com.ibm.*"/>
                <exclude name="com.ibm.*/**"/>
            </fileset>
        </delete>
    </target>

</project>
```